# Quantum harmonic oscillator substitution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, notation

The Schrödinger equation for the harmonic oscillator is
$$\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2\right)\psi(x)=E\psi(x).$$
Then often $x$ gets substituted with $x=\xi a$, where $a=\sqrt{\hbar/m\omega}$, which leads to
$$\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}+\xi^2\right)\psi(\xi)=E\psi(\xi). $$
So my question is if now it should not be $\psi(a\xi)$, or do they define $\psi^\prime(\xi)= \psi(a\xi) $ and then rename it?

Comment: The question is actually about math.

Comment: Can you give the source of this?

Comment: @RogerVadim I think this question still fits best at physics stack exchange. Many more physicists than mathematicians have worked with the Schrödinger equation and just because a physics concept contains math doesn't mean that it is a math question.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I think that question is about general mathematical technique, which is why proposed moving it to the Math community. But I do agree that here it arises in a specific context, which is mostly of interest to physicists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right, one just redefines the $\psi(x)=\psi_{new}(\xi)=\psi(a\xi)$. The Schrödinger equation is thus
$$\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\left(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}+\xi^2\right)\psi_{new}(\xi)=E\psi_{new}(\xi) $$
The basic motivation is to non dimensionalize the independent variable. In order to recover the original $\psi(x)$, we have $$\psi(x)=\psi_{new}(\frac{x}{a})$$

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, to perform such an operation properly, one has to define a new function
$$\phi(\xi)=\phi(ax)=\psi(x).$$
More generally, when defining new variable(s) $\zeta(x)$ one has
$$\phi(\xi)=\phi(\xi(x))=\psi(x).$$ One can then calculate the derivatives as, e.g.,
$$\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}=\frac{d\phi(\xi)}{dx}=\frac{d\phi(\xi)}{d\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dx},\\
\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2\phi(\xi)}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2\phi(\xi)}{d\xi^2}\left(\frac{d\xi}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{d\phi(\xi)}{d\xi}\frac{d^2\xi}{dx^2},$$
and so on.